# Array Modifier duplicating in wrong direction

Tags: modifiers

I'm working on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFLtCi6yWnA) tutorial and when I get to around 45:45 when he starts array modifying the floor with the desks, I got the floors to go up and line up correctly but when I try to array the desks they go down and they're on the X axis instead of the Z. Here's a picture of what's happening. [image] My median point dots are also all over the place and it makes them hard to follow, if there's any info on how to fix of prevent that I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you should have to do is apply the rotation. The hotkey to do this is CTRL + A -> Rotation.

An alternate method (that you probably shouldn't use if you want it duplicated on the x) is to put the value of one in some of the other value boxes (make the current on 0 first).

Comment: Also try messing with the directional factors on the left of the mod panel. Sometimes array gets stuck and needs a jiggle.

Comment: I ended up deleting all the duplicate desks and did your ctrl+a suggestion to the them. Then I added the array and duplicated and that seems to have fixed the problem, so thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.